# How to access variables of class student from class lector?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want `st()` to return the `student`'s `name`.

But why am I getting the empty `list`?

How will I get the name of the `student` class in a `lecturer` class?

```
class student:
    def __init__(self,*name):
        self.name=list(name)

    def stud(self):
        return self.name

stu=student("david","nick")
print(stu.stud())

class lector(student):
    def st(self):
        return self.name

lec=lector()
print(lec.st())
```

Result:

```
['david', 'nick']
[]
```

Comment: class `lector` doesn't have a `call` method defined

Comment: That `lector` class doesn't make much sense. Why is it a child class of `student`?  Your whole question is hard to understand. You need to explain your task better if you want help with this. And I think you should study your Python textbook or tutorial some more, so that you have a better understanding of how classes work in Python.

Comment: You're setting the `lector`'s name to  `[]` by calling `lec=lector()`

Comment: how edit code??

Comment: no. How to correct the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1). There is no `call()` function inside class `lector`. 
2). I have modified your code to get result:-

```
class student:

    def __init__(self,*name):
        student.name=list(name)

    def stud(self):
        return student.name
stu=student("david","nick")
print(stu.stud())

class lector(student):
    def __init__(self):  # Now you can access the variable which are inside student classs
        super
    def st(self):       
        return lector.name

lec=lector()
print(lec.st())
```

I hope it will help you.